# Facebook React: Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: getDOMNode(): A component must be mounted to have a DOM node

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I have the following error within reactjs internals:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: getDOMNode(): A component must be mounted to have a DOM node

What does it mean? What can I do about it?

the stack trace:

```
invariantDev react.js:14392
ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment.Mixin.getDOMNode react.js:4072
React.createClass.scrollToBottom app.js:14124
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: You're calling `getDOMNode` within a component before `React.renderComponent` or before the component is being rendered by a parent component.

Comment: @ssorallen: you should make it an answer

Comment: @tungd I was waiting to see the OP's code so someone else or I could give an exact answer. I was guessing based on the error message, but I'm not confident it will help since there's no code to read.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're using *getDOMNode* before the component has been rendered in the DOM.

You can use *componentDidMount* to wait to run code until the component has been mounted:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // do stuff here that requires the DOM to exist
}
```

you can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)